# Move files to directories based on some part of file name?

Tags: bash, filenames, move

I have several thousand eBooks named like `AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName Title XX.pdf`, where `xx` are number from `1-99` (volume number).

Author tilte name can be of multiple word so here i want to move copy the files to folder with the name `AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName title`. Everything except the number should be the folder name, so that all volumes of the eBook come in same folder.

For example

```
root.....>AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName Title>AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName Title XX.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of `find`, `sed` and `bash` script for the task. You have to write it on your own though and ask for help if you fail.

You can also try some ready tools for mass moving/renaming like these: http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/mass-rename.html
Never used one of these though.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with this:

```
for folder in $(ls | sed -r "s/(.*) ([0-9]{1,2})/\1/" | uniq)
do 
    mkdir $folder
    mv $(find . -name "$folder*") $folder
done
```

I don't know if this is correct, but it may give you some hints.

edit: added uniq to the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop as shown below:

```
find . -type f -name "*pdf" -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file
do
    # extract the name of the directory to create
    dirName="${file% *}"

    # create the directory if it doesn't exist
    [[ ! -d "$dirName" ]] && mkdir "$dirName"

    mv "$file" "$dirName"
done
```