# Batch script to move files to folders based on part of file name

Tags: batch-file, file-moving

I have a relatively simple but time consuming task of moving certain files to designated folders.

Example File names:

```
01234567.Description.Date.FileExtension
89ABCDEF.Description.Date.FileExtension
```

Example Folders:

```
01234567
89ABCDEF
```

All are within a folder, I just want a script that reads the first portion of the name of the file up to the period **`.`** and move that file to the matching folder.

I have tried the following solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26916796/8766357) but I think @Thomas-The-Bombest answer below should be enough to manipulate it to do what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you

Comment: The fact that you state you are not a programmer does not absolve you from making any attempt whatsoever from manipulating the solutions you found. Without providing your code and an explanation of what the issue's are with it in running, your question is a direct code request and is off topic here. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46714028/edit) including the information I have requested above.

Comment: And the sub-folders are within that main folder?

Comment: @Squashman yes the sub-folders are within that main folder.

Comment: @Compo I've edited my response. Apologies, I was not aware direct code requests are not permitted.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `cut -d. -f1` to grab the whatever is before the first `.`

Simply store this in a variable and use it to name a folder with the `mkdir` command

i.e.

`$folderName = echo  01234567.Description.Date.FileExtension | cut -d. -f1`

`mkdir /path/to/wherever/$folderName`

Comment: Thomas, hover your cursor over the batch-file tag, and decide if this answer seems relevant!

Comment: I thought Unix shells required back ticks to assign the output of the command to a variable.

Comment: @Thomas-The-Bombest thanks I should be able to incorporate your code to this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26916796/8766357) and have this work.

Comment: @HashiMohamed, I know you never specified your Operating System or platform and that you are a beginner so I'm just letting you know that the code above is not for a standard Windows platform.